# Other's side video is not showing in Twilio Video calling in react-native. Calling between Web and android

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, twilio, twilio-api

I'm using this library for twilio video calling https://github.com/blackuy/react-native-twilio-video-webrtc
The participant view is showing black after connection. I'm not getting any error. Values are coming in `_onParticipantAddedVideoTrack`. Other callbacks are working.

```
_onParticipantAddedVideoTrack = ({ participant, track }) => {
    //console.warn("onParticipantAddedVideoTrack: ", participant, track)
    console.log("conference 10 ", participant, track);
    this.setState({
      videoTracks: new Map([
        ...this.state.videoTracks,
        [track.trackSid, { participantSid: participant.sid, videoTrackSid: track.trackSid }]
      ]),
    });

    this.setState({
      trackSid: track.trackSid, isParticipant: true,
      trackIdentifier: { participantSid: participant.sid, videoTrackSid: track.trackSid }
    });

  }

<TwilioVideoParticipantView
          style={styles.remoteVideo}
          key={this.state.trackSid}
          enabled={true}
          trackIdentifier={this.state.trackIdentifier}
        />
```

Comment: is it solved? I faced a similar issue and solved it, let me know if you want me to share my findings here.

Comment: @KartikMalik Can you please share your findings? I am having similar issues with Twilio Video JS SDK, maybe they are related

Comment: My findings are specific to react-native, basically, if we position it as "absolute" then for some reason Twilio video stop working properly. I know it is weird but I have tried it in 2-3 different applications.